# Debug Mode in .NET Web Application Prevents Application Page from Loading

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASPNET WEB Application application to use with .NET 6.0. When I set a breakpoint to debug a code gateway in any Controller version, the login page, which is the landing page of the application, is loaded. The login page hangs while loading and the page resources are fully loaded on the host. I can't get to a different page either.

When I remove or disable the debug breakpoint, the application pages open. A piece of code that works regardless of the debug landing page where I set the debug breakpoint, and will not fire at all unless triggered via the URL.

There is probably a problem with the debug settings, but I could not identify the cause of the problem. The application does not have any errors or warnings.

Looking forward to your ideas for help, thank you.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: Can be anything. You're not sharing any relevant information, so it's impossible to help. This can be quite hard to debug without having the **_complete_** app and steps you take.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using Visual Studio 2022 IDE. I've never had the problem I'm having before. I found that it was caused by a bug in the IDE that came with the last update. When I roll back the version, there is no problem, when I update the version, the problem continues, my determination was in this direction.